# html bookmarks not working for ul tab panel

Tags: html, bookmarks

I want to open a hidden id bookmark from external page
it is not working with me

So when I open the link for example: (page.php#translator2)

it gives only the top buttons and no content below

please advise

```html
<div class='profile_main_column column ' style='margin-top: 10px;'>
  <ul class='nav nav-tabs' role='tablist' id='profileTabs'>
    <li role='presentation'><a href='#translator1' aria-controls='translator1' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>translator1_name </a></li>
    <li role='presentation'><a href='#translator2' aria-controls='translator2' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>$translator2_name</a></li>
    <li role='presentation'><a href='#translator3' aria-controls='translator3' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>$translator3_name</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class='tab-content'>
    <div role='tabpanel' class='tab-pane ' id='translator1'>
      <div>
        <u><b>title1</b></u> body1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div role='tabpanel' class='tab-pane ' id='translator2'>
      <div>
        <u><b>title2</b></u> body2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div role='tabpanel' class='tab-pane ' id='translator3'>
      <div>
        <u><b>title3</b></u> body3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `class="active"` in first tab after `tab-pane`, I hope it'll resolve your issue. Thanks

If you want show your `tabs` depending on **hash** in URL you have to add below script in your `$(document).ready` method.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash != '') {
  $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

```js
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash != '') {
  $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='profile_main_column column ' style='margin-top: 10px;'>
  <ul class='nav nav-tabs' role='tablist' id='profileTabs'>
    <li role='presentation'><a href='#translator1' class="active" aria-controls='translator1' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>translator1_name </a></li>
    <li role='presentation'><a href='#translator2' aria-controls='translator2' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>$translator2_name</a></li>
    <li role='presentation'><a href='#translator3' aria-controls='translator3' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>$translator3_name</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class='tab-content'>
    <div role='tabpanel' class='tab-pane active' id='translator1'>
      <div>
        <u><b>title1</b></u> body1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div role='tabpanel' class='tab-pane ' id='translator2'>
      <div>
        <u><b>title2</b></u> body2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div role='tabpanel' class='tab-pane ' id='translator3'>
      <div>
        <u><b>title3</b></u> body3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, Add `active` class in the first tab after `tab-pane`. I also update the above code snippet. Thanks

Comment: thank you, this activates the first div, but it didn`t solve my problem of redirecting to the other hidden divs by their id, please help me if you can, I appreciate it

Comment: The tabs are working fine you have to add bootstrap, jquery libraries. I just update the above code snippet. Thanks

Comment: also not working, redirecting to the other hidden divs by their id not working

Comment: I dont know if my problem descriotion was clear, but I want to open the second tab for example when I enter the link like this: index.php#translator2

Comment: @hasanhasan i just update the above code snippet as your requirement. Now if pass **hash** in your **URL** like `index.php#translator2` it will active the 2nd tab. Thanks